# awk to compare value of sub-string in field

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to extract and compare each substring in `$4` that stars with `p.`. If the first three letters is the same as the last three (there is a digit in between) then that `p.` is updated to `p.(3 letters)(digit)(=)` --- the `()` are only to show that there are 3 enteries and are not needed. If the `3 letters` are different then that line is unchanged. In the below `file` line 1 in an example. In my actual data there are about 10,000 rows wth about 50 columns, but `$4` is the only one that will have these values in ut, that is te `p.` The format of the `p.` will always be three letters followed by a 1-4 digit # followed by 3 more letters. The `awk` attempt below I think will extract each `p.` and split on the `;`, but I am not sure how to compare to check if the three letters are the same.  Thank you :).

**file**  `tab-delimited`

```
Chr Start   ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene
chr1    155880573   synonymous SNV  RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110Glu;RIT1:NM_001256822:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110Glu
chr1    155880573   nonsynonymous SNV   RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu11Gln
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimited`

```
Chr Start   ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene
chr1    155880573   synonymous SNV  RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=;RIT1:NM_001256822:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=
chr1    155880573   nonsynonymous SNV   RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu11Gln
```

**awk**

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
$4 ~ /:NM/ {
ostring=""
# split $4 by ";" and cycle through them
nNM=split($4,NM,";")
for (n=1; n<=nNM; n++) {
  if (n>1) ostring=(ostring ";") # append ";"
   if (match(NM[n],/p[.].*/)) {
     # copy up to "p."
     ostring=(ostring substr(NM[n],1,RSTART+1))
     # Get the substring after "p."
     VAL=substr(NM[n],RSTART+2)
     # Get its length
     lenVAL=length(VAL)
     # store aa array
     aa=[{while(length($4)=3){print substr($044,1,3);gsub(/^./,"")}]}' file
```

Comment: Chris, it is not clear. Please post more details how you are getting output shown by you.

Comment: `aa=[{while(length($4)=3){print substr($044,1,3);gsub(/^./,"")}]` isn't remotely awk syntax and what is `$044` in the substr() even supposed to mean? You've been asking awk questions long enough now (2 years!) that this lack of fundamental understanding is shocking. Also this is a very trivial problem to solve so after 2 years of awk programming you shouldn't even have to ask how to do it. Take some time to read Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as clearly you're not picking up awk syntax/semantics the way you're going so far.

Comment: I have read and continually refer to Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. I have learned a lot but yes, semantics/concepts can be somewhat confusing. I always try and am always learning and impressed by everyone's knowledge and skills. Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR > 1{ 
         len = split($4, a, /\<p\.[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{3}\>/, seps);
         if (len == 1){ print; next }
         res = "" 
         for (i=1; i < len; i++) {
             s = seps[i]; 
             if (substr(s, 3, 3) == substr(s, length(s) - 2)) {
                 seps[i] = substr(s, 1, length(s) - 3)"="; 
             }
         } 
         for (i=1; i <= len; i++) 
             res = res a[i] (seps[i]? seps[i]:""); 
         $4 = res; print 
     }' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
Chr Start   ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene
chr1    155880573   synonymous SNV  RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=;RIT1:NM_001256822:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=
chr1    155880573   nonsynonymous SNV   RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu11Gln
```

---

Time performance measurement:

Input `testfile`:

```
$ wc -l testfile
10000 testfile
```

---

```
time(awk 'NR==1; NR > 1{ 
         len = split($4, a, /\<p\.[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{3}\>/, seps);
         if (len == 1){ print; next }
         res = "" 
         for (i=1; i < len; i++) {
             s = seps[i]; 
             if (substr(s, 3, 3) == substr(s, length(s) - 2)) {
                 seps[i] = substr(s, 1, length(s) - 3)"="; 
             }
         } 
         for (i=1; i <= len; i++) 
             res = res a[i] (seps[i]? seps[i]:""); 
         $4 = res; print 
     }' FS='\t' OFS='\t' testfile >/dev/null)

real    0m0.269s
user    0m0.256s
sys 0m0.000s
```

---

```
time(awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR>1 {
    head = ""
    tail = $4
    while ( match(tail,/(p\.([[:alpha:]]{3})[0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]{3})/,a) ) {
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) a[1] (a[2] == a[3] ? "=" : a[3])
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $4 = head tail
}
{ print }' testfile >/dev/null)

real    0m0.470s
user    0m0.416s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR>1 {
    head = ""
    tail = $4
    while ( match(tail,/(p\.([[:alpha:]]{3})[0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]{3})/,a) ) {
        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) a[1] (a[2] == a[3] ? "=" : a[3])
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $4 = head tail
}
{ print }

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
Chr Start   ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene
chr1    155880573   synonymous SNV  RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=;RIT1:NM_001256822:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu110=
chr1    155880573   nonsynonymous SNV   RIT1:NM_001256821:exon2:c.31G>C:p.Glu11Gln
```